# Agregar datos dinamicos a selectpicker con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo el siguiente selectpicker:

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="UsersList" data-live- 
 search="true" title="Seleccione uno o varios usuarios" data-hide- 
 disabled="true" data-actions-box="true" multiple>
 <option value="1">Carlos Valencia/option>
 <option value="2">Andres Lopez/option>
 </select>
```

y en javascript quiero cargar datos dinámicamente de la siguiente manera:

```
function User_Rad(idSettled) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Administrador/Radicados/User_Rad",
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { idSettled: idSettled },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            var options = [], _options;
            //var option;

            for (var i = 0; i < response.User_assigned.length; i++)
            {
                var  option = '<option value="' + response.User_assigned[i].IdUser + '">' + response.User_assigned[i].Names + " " + response.User_assigned[i].Surname + '</option>';
                    options.push(option);

            }
            _options = options.join('');

            $('#UsersList').innerHTML = _options;

        },
        error: function (data, status, error) {
            console.log(data + " - " + status + " - " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero los datos no se visualizan más que los que quedan directo desde HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación del ***selectpicker*** tiene un método llamado **[refresh](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)** que dice lo siguiente:

> Para actualizar mediante programación una selección con JavaScript, primero manipule la selección, luego use el método de actualización para actualizar la interfaz de usuario para que coincida con el nuevo estado. Esto es necesario al eliminar o agregar opciones, o al deshabilitar / habilitar una selección a través de JavaScript.

En tú caso deberías hacer:

```
$('#UsersList').html(_options);
$('#UsersList').selectpicker('refresh');
```

O todo es una sola línea:

```
$('#UsersList').html(_options).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el refresh mostro los datos correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para reemplazar el contenido HTML de un elemento con jQuery, debes usar el método `.html()`, [ver documentación.](https://api.jquery.com/html/) En este orden de ideas tu código debería quedar así:

```js
function User_Rad(idSettled) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Administrador/Radicados/User_Rad",
    datatype: "Json",
    data: {
      idSettled: idSettled
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      var options = [],
        _options;
      //var option;

      for (var i = 0; i < response.User_assigned.length; i++) {
        var option = '<option value="' + response.User_assigned[i].IdUser + '">' + response.User_assigned[i].Names + " " + response.User_assigned[i].Surname + '</option>';
        options.push(option);

      }
      _options = options.join('');

      $('#UsersList').html(_options);

    },
    error: function(data, status, error) {
      console.log(data + " - " + status + " - " + error);
    }
  });
}
```